# how to display multiple bars in barplot in pandas for csv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Below is my code but I want to display two bars in the bar plot (one bar for mean, and another bar for sem)

```
def stderrtests(filename):
    stderror = dict(data2[['Test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7']].sem())
    means = dict(data2[['Test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7']].mean())
    plt.bar(stderror.keys(),stderror.values())
    plt.bar(means.values(),means.keys())
stderrtests("exams_resuts.csv")
```

---

i want to display the below graph:

[image]

Comment: Usually, you have error bars to display the SEM. Are you sure, you want to plot these values as another group of bars? How to plot multiple groups in a bar chart is explained in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#bar-plots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
'''
First, you choose the columns that are to be displayed in the graph:
'''
df = df[['Test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7']]
means = df.mean()
stds = df.std()
columns = df.columns

'''
Now, you determine the locations for the two bars as well as for the x ticks:
'''
bar_mean_x = [i for i in range(len(columns))]
bar_std_x = [i + 0.3 for i in bar_mean_x]
x_ticks = [i + 0.15 for i in bar_mean_x]

'''
Finally, you plot the bars for mean and std, update the xticks with the column labels and show the plot!
'''
plt.bar(bar_mean_x, means, color = 'b', width = 0.3)
plt.bar(bar_std_x, stds, color = 'g', width = 0.3)
plt.xticks(x_ticks, columns)
plt.legend(["Mean", "Standard Deviation"])
plt.show()
```

Unrelated, but may be nice to change the coloring by picking a colormap and choosing the colors of the bars from there:

```py
import matplotlib
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('gist_earth')

'''
And then in the Code you change the plt.bar lines to:
'''
plt.bar(bar_mean_x, means, color = cmap(0.3), width = 0.3)
plt.bar(bar_std_x, stds, color = cmap(0.5), width = 0.3)
```